# How to use an Adobe fresco vector image save in PNG format and uploaded through flutterflow's custom icon button

Tags: fonts, icon, file-format, adobe-fresco, visual-studio-code

When designing apps using the flutterflow program there is a section on the home page of the app project you are building that is able to upload images as a truetype font file , otherwise if I instead select a PNG of the image it then asks me to upload an icon info which is a link under the title Icon Dart File. I'm not sure if I'm just unaware of the correct file type the image should be saved as, or if I need to convert the image into a file I can upload from dart

Answer (score 0):

I've never used flutterflow, but a quick google search found [this tutorial on youtube](https://youtu.be/fJ8tCE_767A) which seems to suggest you need an SVG for custom icons. SVG is a vector image format. PNG is a raster image format.  Since I'm unfamiliar with the software, there might be a way to use raster images (I'd be surprised if there wasn't), but it's probably better to ask for support on flutterflow's user forum. I doubt many here will be familiar with flutterflow since it's a developer tool rather than a graphic design tool.

I'm not an Adobe Fresco user either, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation that says you can export SVGs or vectors from Adobe Fresco. It appears to be a digital painting app which suggests output is raster only.

It might be better to design your icon in an actual vector image editor, such as Illustrator or Inkscape, then you can export as SVG for use in flutterflow.